Help identify this SOT-23 5 pin component labeled ADU06 and weird behavior
I'm new to fixing circuits and I'm trying to figure out why this board will not boot. I've traced the Vcc on the MCU (H8/38024) to this circuit.
I'm guessing that it is a linear regulator, but when I power on the board the output (to the MCU) fluctuates between 1.2 and 1.9V rapidly on my multimeter. I cannot trace the top two leads to anything on the board.
Could it be that the linear regulator (if it is one) is bad? Do linear regulator fail in a way that I would pick it up as rapidly fluctuations between 1.2 and 1.9 on my multimeter?
Thank you for any insight you may have! Happy to provide more photos or answer any questions.


Are you sure that pin 2 is Vin? Which pin is ground? Where did you measure the fluctuations?

From the image, we can see that it is connected to Pin 12 of the MCU. In the image from the datasheet we can see that this is a reset pin. 
So this component is probably a voltage supervisor that has an open collector output which will pull the reset line low on startup for a certain amount of time and when the voltage crosses a certain threshold.
What your multimeter is showing is probably crap (at least the values) but fluctuating means that something is going on on that line. And this could be an issue. There could be several more reset sources on that line, finding the one that causes issues (if that's the issue at all) can be a challenge.
So what could the problem be?

As you already pointed out: it could be this supervisor IC that's broken
It could be that Vcc is fluctuating which would cause the supervisor IC to issue resets as it should (maybe the MCU causes something to pull more current as soon as it comes out of reset making Vcc drop which will cause a reset which will reduce the load which will make the reset condition go away which will let the MCU start again and the whole circle starts again.

So your multimeter showing fluctuating values is often an indication of higher frequency stuff going on on that line.

I was reading the data sheet wrong! Oof! Thank you so much for you help. I'll re-do my investigation with the correct eyeballs and try again!

Do you have any additional resources I could look for to help debug my dead board? I appreciate your detailed answer and it shed light on where to look, but as a novice I find it quite overwhelming to dig in deeper.
